# Why do Safari links with target="_blank" download an HTML instead of opening the page in a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, safari, cross-browser

I have a page with some links like this:

```html
<a href="https://something.com/url/" target="_blank">link text</a>
```

On all browsers it works as expected, opening the page in a new tab, BUT on Safari clicking on the link downloads an HTML page with the content of the link. WHY?!!?

It's driving me insane.

Note: I'm setting the href attribute dynamically from JS, could that be the cause?

thanks!

Comment: Is that really related tot he `target="_blank"`? Is it working if you don't use that attribute?

Comment: Are there any `Content-Disposition` HTTP headers or meta tags on your target link?

Comment: Yes, it seems related to the `target="_blank"` my temporary fix right now is to set `target=''`

Comment: There's nothing special about the target link, just a regular page in WordPress

Comment: @coding-dude.com What is the Content-Type of the page? (You can see that from the browser's developer tools in the network tab.)

Comment: @Ivar it's just a regular page on my website `content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`